# Can you report or otherwise build list by User License Type?

Tags: licenses

We have 4 different license types in our org. "Salesforce," "Force.com - One App," "Chatter Free" and "External Who"

We have a couple hundred users. I need to build a report that lists who has what license. Company Information gives me the Available vs Used, but I need to see the actual users.

Anyway to build a report to display this information?

For a bonus - I would love to be able to do this by feature license as well. To see which users are Marketing Users, Service Cloud User, Content User, Knowledge and Flow Users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a custom formula field with output of text and in the formula field, use this:

Profile.UserLicense.Name

You'll be able to report on the license types then.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SOQL, it's at [select id, **profile.userlicense.name** from User]

Answer (score 1):

You can get most of this from a standard report.  Create a new report using Administrative Reports -> User as the report type.  You can then add the following fields:

1. Profile
2. User Type (Standard seems to be regular Salesforce, CSN is Chatter External)
3. Marketing User (checkbox)
4. Offline User
5. Sales Anywhere User

I'm not sure about Knowledge, Service Cloud or some of the others because we don't have those extras, but they'll probably be there under the Salesforce.com Information bucket in the Report Builder.  You can also count the number of Active users to help determine how many licenses are in use.

Comment: I was hoping User Type == License Type. That doesn't seem to be the case at least it's not universal. I have 3 User License types in use and yet the report shows everyone having a user Type as 'Standard' If we add Chatter + or other Force.com license types it doesn't appear I can find who has it. It's not available in the list view either.